# Would this question if migrated to CS get closed as too general?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, questions

[When is the language said to be context free?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20139074/1243762)

I saw this question and knew that it could get better answers here at CS, but didn't flag it for migration as it had a few answers but more importantly thought it might get closed as too general.

Would you close it as too general, or something else, or believe that it should be migrated to CS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think this question would be closed as too broad.

Generally speaking, if a good answer to “what is X” is “read the Wikipedia article whose title is X”, there's no point in duplicating Wikipedia's content on Stack Exchange.

See [Is it okay to ask questions here when Wikipedia already has the answer?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377/is-it-okay-to-ask-questions-here-when-wikipedia-already-has-the-answer)